# how to highlight whole row and scroll to it if matched value?

Tags: excel, vba

I have sheet 1 with range of names. I have a msg box input where I can just click the cell referencing the value. If it matches, it finds where that value lies in column C of sheet 2. It works how I want it to, but I need to figure out how to highlight the *whole* row. Also, is there a scroll to indexing I can do to make sure it moves down sheet 2 to where that row was highlighted?

Code:

```
Sub tgr()
Dim rFound As Range
Dim lemployee As String
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rw As Long
Dim matched As Boolean

lemployee = Application.InputBox("Please selct an employee", "Employee Name", Type:=2)

If lemployee = "False" Then Exit Sub
Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
rw = 2

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns("C")
    Set rFound = .Find(lemployee, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)
            If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(rFound.Row, 3).Value = lemployee Then
                .Cells(rFound.Row).Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(255, 255, 0)
            End If




End With



End Sub
```

EDIT: As for the scroll, I would just need something like:

```
Application. Goto ActiveCell.EntireRow,True
```

Comment: `rFound.EntireRow.Interior.Color`

Comment: how would I implement the scrolling to that active row where the value on sheet2 matched the msg box value?

Comment: `rFound.Select` will select it, jumping to that position in the Excel doc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns("C")
    Set rFound = .Find(lemployee, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        rFound.EntireRow.Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(255, 255, 0)
        Application.Goto rFound
    End If
End With
```